# express route handler context is global (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, routes, this

The route handler context is global? This makes it nearly impossible to pass an instance method of a class, or am I wrong here?

For example:

```
App.all('/anyRoute', instanciatedClass.REST);
```

Where as .REST is a method on that instance.
If this route is called, i just wanted to call another method on that class instance, but it is not available as **this** within the function seems to be the global context of the node app.

Anyone any ideas?
Didn't find any apply/call in express where the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're just passing the function itself. Once you do that, the context is gone.

There's at least two solutions for this:

1. Create a wrapper function:

   ```
   App.all('/anyRoute', function(req, res, next) {
     instanciatedClass.REST(req, res, next);
   });
   ```
2. Use `function.bind()` to bind the desired context to the function:

   ```
   App.all('/anyRoute', instanciatedClass.REST.bind(instanciatedClass));
   ```

On an unrelated note, you might consider doing `App.use()` instead of `App.all()`, since the latter will add a separate route handler for every supported HTTP method, whereas the former will add just one route handler that still catches everything.